# Get date modified of a folder

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I want to access last modified date-time, written in "date modified" column in windows, for a folder.
I can do this for a file using

```
forfiles /P "C:\Users" /S /D -10  | find /c /v
```

but how to do it for a folder?

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of erroneous pipe to `find` and in view of next two commands give the same output:

- `forfiles /P "C:\Users" /S /D -10`
- `forfiles /P "C:\Users" /S /D -10 /C "cmd /C echo @file"`

Hence, next command outputs *folder* names (fully qualified paths, in a matter of fact) only:

```
forfiles /P "C:\USERS" /d -10  /C "cmd /C if /I @isdir==true echo @path"
```

Read `forfiles /?` or [FORFILES.exe: Select a file (or set of files) and execute a command on each file](http://ss64.com/nt/forfiles.html).